# What to do when multiple answers taken together compose a complete answer?

Tags: discussion

I have received a bunch of help regarding my question [How to extract slope from topographic raster map?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41991/how-to-extract-slope-from-topographic-raster-map/42026#comment54856_42026) As such I have resolved my problem. However no "answer" comprises the complete answer. In fact I needed the information from all three respondents. Is it better to 1) summarize the salient points into an answer and accept my own answer, 2) accept one of the three answers provided, or 3) something all together different?

Answer (score 10):

I would comment on all the responses, asking them to integrate the needed information from others. Remind them I want to accept the best answer, but haven't got one yet, a form of classical SE gamification.

There are three major possible outcomes:

1. Nothing happens. You can increase the chances by adding a bounty to
   the question. If you don't feel that's appropriate and none of the
   existing answers is good enough, add the best answer yourself.
   Accepting your own answers is nothing to shy from.
2. One member takes the bait and trivial resolution follows.
3. More than one member makes the attempt. Even better, you get a
   choice between excellent answers and the site is better off with more good content.

All the editing will also bump the thread in the "active" list, so likely more people will see the question, consider participating and vote on the answers, helping you choose the best.

Comment: A good summary. In my experience #1 happens most often (and that's okay). People seem to shy away from revamping "old" questions (not so ok, but the way it is).

Answer (score 3):

As you pointed out with option 1, you can answer your own question, which is sometimes the recommended approach on other sites. Integrate the answers into one clear response for future reference, and upvote those that helped, while accepting your own answer.